# equivalent of default value during Converting my newtonsoft implementation to new JSON library in .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, json.net, .net-core-3.0, system.text.json

I am converting my .net core 2.1 to 3.0 with upgrade from newtonsoft to builtin JSON serializer.

I have some code for setting default value

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
[JsonProperty("send_service_notification", DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Populate)]
public bool SendServiceNotification { get; set; }
```

Please help me out with equivalent in System.Text.Json.Serialization.

Comment: No direct equivalent exists yet in `System.Text.Json`, see [System.Text.Json option to ignore default values in serialization & deserialization #38878](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38878).  But, to reproduce `DefaultValueHandling.Populate`, you could always set the default values in the constructor.

Comment: I have an implementation that if in posted json someone not sent the property i consider it as true, otherwise if someone sent it it can be true or false as posted

Comment: So what if you do `public bool SendServiceNotification { get; set; } = true;`, is that sufficient?

Comment: Thanks dbc. constructor related thing has worked. But it could be better if there is similar sort of attribute added in new System.Text.Json so that porting can be ease

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As noted in *[Issue #38878: System.Text.Json option to ignore default values in serialization & deserialization](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/38878)*, **as of .Net Core 3** there is no equivalent to the [`DefaultValueHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) functionality in [`System.Text.Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json?view=netcore-3.0).

**.NET 5 and later**  introduce [`JsonIgnoreAttribute.Condition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute.condition?view=net-5.0), which has the following [values](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v5.0.0-rtm.20519.4/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonIgnoreCondition.cs):

> ```
> public enum JsonIgnoreCondition
> {
>     /// Property is never ignored during serialization or deserialization.
>     Never = 0,
>     /// Property is always ignored during serialization and deserialization.
>     Always = 1,
>     /// If the value is the default, the property is ignored during serialization.
>     /// This is applied to both reference and value-type properties and fields.
>     WhenWritingDefault = 2,
>     /// If the value is <see langword="null"/>, the property is ignored during serialization.
>     /// This is applied only to reference-type properties and fields.
>     WhenWritingNull = 3,
> }
> ```

While `JsonIgnoreCondition` superficially resembles `DefaultValueHandling`, System.Text.Json ignores custom default values applied via [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute).  Instead the default value used is always `default(T)`.  E.g. the following combination of attributes:

```
[DefaultValue(true)]
[JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingDefault)]
[JsonPropertyName("send_service_notification")]
public bool SendServiceNotification { get; set; }
```

Will result in `SendServiceNotification` being skipped when `false` not `true`.  In addition, System.Text.Json will not automatically populate the default value onto your model if not present in the JSON.

**That being said**, you are using `DefaultValueHandling.Populate`:

> Members with a default value but no JSON will be set to their default value when deserializing.

If your properties are mutable, this can be achieved by setting the default value in the constructor or property initializer:

```
//[DefaultValue(true)] not needed by System.Text.Json
[System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonPropertyName("send_service_notification")]
public bool SendServiceNotification { get; set; } = true;
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JOJJQe).

If you are using immutable properties that are set only via a parameterized  constructor, in .NET 6 (and possibly .NET 5, I haven't checked) you can specify a default value in the constructor argument list and it will be honored by System.Text.Json when not present in the JSON.  E.g. if you have a record:

```
public record SendServiceRecord (bool SendServiceNotification = true);
```

And you deserialize the JSON `{}`, then `SendServiceNotification` will be true after deserialization.

See demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTQmR8) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tTlgUk).

In fact the [documentation for `DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netcore-3.0#remarks) recommends code initialization of default values:

> A [`DefaultValueAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute?view=netcore-3.0) will not cause a member to be automatically initialized with the attribute's value. You must set the initial value in your code.

Comment: When the serializer calls a constructor that sets the property, just the property initializer is not enough. DefaultValueHandling.Populate works in that case and there is no way that I know of to make it work with System.Text.Json. On the project I am working on, we have many such classes as we tend to work with immutable records.

Comment: @Palec - using default values in record constructors seems to work.  I.e. if I define a record `public record Person(string FirstName = "default first name", string LastName = "default last name");` and deserialize the JSON `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Person>("{\"FirstName\":\"first name\"}")` then `person.LastName` is `"default last name"` as required.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/xjshth or https://dotnetfiddle.net/mTQmR8 for examples.  Is that what you need?

Comment: We have our own source generator for record-like classes as we need an extra feature the standard records do not have, but this should translate well to optional arguments of the constructor. Thanks! The default becomes optional in the constructor, but that might be acceptable.

Comment: Still, the JSON.NET way is a bit better. We serialize some data into JSON and store the JSON in persistent storage. When we load the data again, it might be in a later version of the app. Sometimes we decide to add e.g. a boolean property to the record and we want that property to be always explicitly specified so that we do not forget to fill it when we create the record in code. But when deserializing, it might be missing (old data is read) and we want to fill `true` in that case. (For some properties, `default` is OK, but we have cases where another value is better.)

Comment: Then stick with Json.NET for now, and open an enhancement issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+label%3Aarea-System.Text.Json).  Json.NET isn't going away or anything, it's not like `JavaScriptSerializer` which you really should not use since it hasn't been ported to .NET Core (and never will be).

Comment: That's what we are doing. We just keep looking towards System.Text.Json as it is an integral part of the platform and it might provide much better perf once we are able to use it.